# How to populate input text field data based on button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In my project i have 10 products for every product i have button called info, if i click on a info button a form popups in that i wanted to fill the first field(product name) automatically ....lets say for product soap i have info button

```
                  `<a href="" id="1" class="btn">info</a>`
```

In the form

```
               `<form>
            <input type="text" id="product_name">
           <input type="text" id="number">
     </form>`
```

I want the field Product_name to be filled automatically based on button pressed
so how to get this ..plz help 
i tried using 
             `<a href="" id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">info</a>`
and my js

```
function  reply_click(clicked_id)
{
//alert(clicked_id);
 if(clicked_id == "1")
 {
  document.getElementById(product_name).value='Soap';   
 }
 else
 {
 alert("button not pressed");
 }

 }
```

i tried this logic for example, i am able to read button click but iam unable to write to form...
some one please help me out
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Suman, you need to provide 'product_name' as a string to getElementById(). Here is a working example of your approach: http://jsfiddle.net/CTnFt/

But since you will likely have many of these  tags for many products, a simpler solution might be to place the value in a data- attribute of your  tag and read it in your javascript function, instead of a larger, harder to maintain collection of if/elses. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9MG/

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="btn" onclick="reply_click(this)" data-product-name="Soap">info</a>

<form>

    <input type="text" id="product_name" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function reply_click(element)
    {
        document.getElementById('product_name').value = element.getAttribute('data-product-name');
    }    

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using id without quotes `product_name` but `'product_name'`

should be

```
 document.getElementById('product_name').value='Soap';
```

instead of

```
  document.getElementById(product_name).value='Soap';
```

Comment: Just to add some clarification the way the OP has used it product_name would be a variable. If you intend it to be a string then it needs to be wrapped in quotes. Answer has been updated to clarify :P

Comment: @CarlMarkham that's the main problem, he is using id without quotes other wise OP's code is fine.

Comment: I know, I just thought I would add that for the OP incase it wasn't just a simple typo and they didn't understand.

Comment: hey thank you so much now it s working fine, actually i am new to javascript